# How to identify customers who bought first time, second time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called order_details which contains 4 columns

customer_id,payment_id,payment_date,item_name

I need to find the customer_ids of those customers who paid for an item today, tomorrow or so. But I only want his/her 2 entries not more than that. For eg:- If he/she bought 2 items on 1st Jan then I will consider 2 entries for Jan 1st and after that, if he/she bought other items I don't want to insert those records in my new table. same if he/she paid for 1 item on 1st Jan then I want his/her second's entry as well in if he/she paid on 2nd Jan and so.

The customer has paid for 2 items each and he/she can get rewards for 1st and 2nd time but not for the 3rd time

my table looks like this -

```
create table order_details(

customer_id varchar(10),
payment_id varchar(10),
payment_date varchar(10),
item_name varchar(10))

insert into order_details values
('A','C01','2022-01-01',Laptop),
('A','C02','2022-01-01',Pain Drive),
('A','C03','2022-01-02',Music System),
('B','B01','2022-01-01',Stationary),
('C','D01','2022-01-01',Fruits)
```

I used row_number and after that, I am able to filter records like where row_numbre <=2. But I want my table to be updated so it will automatically delete the records which already received the rewards. Thanks!

Comment: Show desired output for this sample data.

Comment: Thanks for checking, My desired output should be A for 2 times, and for the next day, if he/she is eligible, I don't want to include him/her.

Comment: Which database service are you using? Are you using MySQL or BigQuery?